# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm starting off with jni and trying to get a simple HelloWorld example working. I'm having a linkage error which I'm guessing has to do with my native library not pointing to the correct file path.

I have to use the command: 
java -Djava.library.path= ??

What do I set this to? All my so files are in a app/src/main/libs/armeabi/libHelloJni.so , libs/x86/libHelloWorld.so, and so on.

I'm currently doing:

```
static {
   System.loadLibrary("HelloJni")
}
```

Comment: hmm I think this is the naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .so files should be placed in app/src/main/jniLibs/ folder. In your case, it should be app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libHelloJni.so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure app's build.gradle is OK and my *.so also OK. After reading official doc my problem is from Android Studio 3.0 and encounter this problem

Go to Run -> Edit Configurations -> Profiling, and disable "Enable advanced profiling".

This works for me